# Power set of a set that includes the the empty set as an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding power sets, specifically power sets of sets that explicitly include the empty set as an element.

In the following example, the subset {∅, 3}, which is a combination of the empty set element and the other element of the original set is included as an element of the power set.

P({∅, 3}) = {∅, {3}, {∅}, {∅, 3}}

I have seen contradictory examples regarding this phenomenon, and am not sure whether all the subsets of the power set should also include a version of themselves that also have the empty set as an element.

More concretely,

I am not sure as to which following power set is the correct one.

P({∅,3,5})={∅,{∅},{3},{5},{3,5},{∅,3,5}}

or

P({∅,3,5})={∅,{∅},{3},{∅,3},{5},{∅,5},{3,5},{∅,3,5}}

I would really appreciate your insight into this question.

Comment: If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three distinct elements, then $P(\{a,b,c\})=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$. Note that it has $8$ elements, not $6$; the power set of an $n$-element set always has exactly $2^n$ elements. In your example $a=\varnothing$, $b=3$, $c=5$, and your last answer is correct. Why would you think otherwise? What was your reason for omitting $\{\varnothing,3\}$ and $\{\varnothing,5\}$?

Comment: I saw examples where such subsets were omitted from the power set, so I was confused about it. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Where did you see those examples? What book was that?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to computing the power set of a set, whether or not it contains the empty set as an element isn't relevant. For example, for any finite set of cardinality $N$ (finite), its power set will have cardinality $2^N$, so in your example, it's the second set which is the correct power set.

The point is the power set of a set $X$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$. We generate subsets of $X$ by considering each element of $X$, and either including it or excluding it. When the empty set happens to be an element of $X$, for our consideration it is only an element of $X$, so it either gets included in a subset *as an element* or it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.